# Convert SimpleDateFormat to String Issues

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

I'm trying to convert SimpleDateFormat to String, but result is not correct.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Log.d("current date",dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,-3);
Log.d("3 years previous date",dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

String valnow = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

Output:

```
01-19 05:34:52.148: DEBUG/current date(556): 19/01/2012
01-19 05:34:52.148: DEBUG/3 years previous date(556): 19/01/2009
```

But `valnow` value = `19/01/2012`.

Could someone please tell me the way to do this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Comment: Could you explain what is the issue you facing. You are giving dateFormat.format(new Date()) and it is giving current date

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I hope to get     String valnow =19/01/2009.but it issues is valnow=19/01/2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing

```
String valnow = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

with

```
String valnow = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long lo = System.currentTimeMillis();
//    long lo = Long.parseLong(date);
    Log.e("Try", "Check "+lo);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d 'at' hh:mm a 'in the year' yyyy G");  
    String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lo);  
    Log.e("Try", "Check Ti`enter code here`me Date "+formattedDateString);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yy", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
```

Comment: this method doesn't exist, check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: Some one downvoted my answer, may i know why??
@VIdre check this >http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html